# How to remove duplicated objects in a array and keep the min value

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I need to remove the duplicates products field and keep the one with the lowest price

```js
var store = [
    {price: 730, product: "BSB", ida: 1614237278000},
    {price: 780, product: "SSA", ida: 1613237278000},
    {price: 832, product: "CWB", ida: 1614237278000},
    {price: 600, product: "POA", ida: 1601942490000},
    {price: 860, product: "POA", ida: 1601942490000},
    {price: 730, product: "BSB", ida: 1614237278000},
    {price: 832, product: "CWB", ida: 1614237278000},
    {price: 600, product: "POA", ida: 1601942490000},
    {price: 1020, product: "POA", ida: 1601942490000}
];
```

The result array that i want after the method is this:

```js
var store = [
    {price: 730, product: "BSB", ida: 1614237278000},
    {price: 780, product: "SSA", ida: 1613237278000},
    {price: 832, product: "CWB", ida: 1614237278000},
    {price: 600, product: "POA", ida: 1601942490000},
];
```

Im trying to do something like this but it wont work

```js
store.map(product => {
    var duplicates = product.filter((product2 , index) => {
        if(product["product"] === product2["product"]) {
            store.splice(index, 1);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });

    var minValueInDuplicates = Math.min(...duplicates.map(d => d["price"]));

    var singleDuplicate = duplicates.find(d => d["price"] === minValueInDuplicates);

    return singleDuplicate;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rule of thumb if the output array has a different length to the input array you don’t want to use map, but filter or in this case reduce.

```
const obj = store.reduce((acc, product) => {
  if (!acc[store.product] || acc[store.product].price > product.price) {
    acc[store.product] = product;
  }
 return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(obj);
```